# vscode jupyter notebook output not showing

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, output

The outputs don't show up including texts, lists and dictionaries even though the cells ran normally without errors. I can only see nothing but one grey line.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj71Z.png)

Dataframes however show up fine as well as plots.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA3Vd.png)

I've got this situation out of nowhere. Does anyone know why??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think this question posts provides a fair amount of detail. But I also think it may be unlikely to get an answer ([/help/no-one-answers](/help/no-one-answers)). Perhaps you could add info about your system (OS version, VS Code version, Python version, extension versions) and see if the problem reproduces if you run with all your settings set to default values.

Comment: This problem is difficult to reproduce. You can try restoring the settings related to python and jupyter to the default state.